# Fail to upload picture into existing row in the table

Tags: php, html

I have a booking table which contain file_name and file_path, I need to upload a picture into the user row based on the noic, after I select a picture and click the upload button, it show upload success, but in the database doesn't have the picture and picture name.

```
$target = "upload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$file=basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename=$_POST['file_name'];


//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
// Connects to your Database


//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE INTO booking (file_path,file_name)
VALUES ('$file', '$filename') WHERE noic = '$_SESSION[noic]'") ;
} else {
//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}



<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="userstatus.php" method="POST">
 <p> File Name :
   <input style="background:grey;" type="text" name="file_name" value="" >
  </p>
   <p>
   <input type="file" name="file" >
    </p>
    <p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file" style="background:grey;">
    </p>
   </form>
```

Comment: Show your form code too!!

Comment: In output form you have add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: yes, i have put enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL query is incorrect, it should be UPDATE  SET... MySQL Insert statement does not support the WHERE clause so your query will fail if you directly replace UPDATE with INSERT, make the following changes,

```
    //Writes the information to the database
    mysql_query("UPDATE booking SET file_path='$file',
      file_name='$filename' WHERE noic = '$_SESSION[noic]'") ;
    }
```

NOTE: PLEASE AVOID USING php mysql* class for database queries, it has been deprecated and should not be used, Switch to PDO or MySQLi. PDO reference - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run your query

```
UPDATE INTO booking (file_path,file_name) VALUES ('$file', '$filename') WHERE noic = '(replace here the noic you want)'
```

On phpMyAdmin or MySql Workbench??

Why don't you try to run the query like this:

```
UPDATE booking SET file_path = '$file', SET file_name= '$filename' WHERE noic = '$_SESSION[noic]'
```

Also check If you have set the 775 permission to the /upload folder..

Hope I help you!